# Postsharp Error after updating newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

I have a .net framework solution, that uses postsharp version 4.2.21.0.

I have a demand to upgrade our newtonsoft.json package from 11.0.2 to 13.0.1. After this upgrade, solution became unable to build, because os this post sharp error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unhandled exception (4.2.21.0, postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.528449, Release):
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at ^e9p3FN6izlJE.^TxMhIJ+U(^EyL1LQX01Ck8 _0)
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleReader.ImportCustomAttributes()
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleReader.ImportCustomAttributes(MetadataDeclaration _0)
  at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.CustomAttributeDeclarationCollection.DoLazyLoading()
  at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.ElementCollection`1.^7qsXyJec()
  at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Collections.ElementCollection`1.GetEnumerator()
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.AnnotationRepositoryTask.^H9TZo5Th(TypeDefDeclaration _0)
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.AnnotationRepositoryTask.^wwGmHrz+(IAnnotationInstance _0)
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.AnnotationRepositoryTask.Execute()
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
  at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
  at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
  at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation).
```

When I downgrade newtonsoft.json back to 11.0.2, solution builds fine.

Is it possible to update this newtonsoft.json withou geting the postsharp error?

Comment: Are you able to update postsharp to a newer version?

Comment: there are to many code chances and references to make to update postsharp. We would not like to go that way for now

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a bug in PostSharp 4.2, released in 2015, but it is currently unsupported. Please update to a supported version.